# Why is Spring INFO logging to Standard Error?

Tags: java, spring, logging, stderr, standard-error

I have a many DB integration tests that are using the following annotations for transactional rollback:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:ApplicationContext-DAOs.xml"})
@Transactional
```

The tests pass, but when I run them Spring deems it necessary to log at INFO level to standard error! It logs things like:

```
19/11/2010 16:49:11 org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager
  retrieveTestExecutionListeners
INFO: @TestExecutionListeners is not present for class [class my.SomeDAOTest]:
  using defaults.
etc for many, many lines ...
```

Where do I turn this off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide it using log4j. In your log4j.xml, set a logger for spring to warn (or error).

```
<logger name="org.springframework">
    <level value="warn"/>
</logger>
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring core is using apache commons logging.  In order to configure away from default behavior (writing to stderr) I had to use the bridge component for my particular framework.

I'm using Log4j2, so once I added the bridge from apache commons to log4j2, then spring core respected my settings.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.2</version>
</dependency>
```